# Plot graphs on google earth dynamically

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-earth-plugin

I would like to know whether graphs can be plotted on google earth dynamically, for example if the data can be provided in the format of json or kml file can it be plotted? If yes can someone give me some idea where to start from and what to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide your data in KML or KMZ format and then [view in google earth](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=41136)
.  KMZ is a compressed format of KML and you can use it to represent a virtual tour on google earth and then share with others using google drive. Check this [video from google](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jjm75hSkqic) on how to do this.

Comment: yes you can. kmz is just a compressed format of kml which is equivalent to compressing kml using winzip. So basically kmz will have a smaller size than the corresponding kml, making it easier for sharing, etc.